# What is the difference between a Swift package and a module?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-package-manager

Swift has modular code, which can be sorted into modules.

But you can use the Swift Package Manager to fetch and install modules.

Is there any difference between a "Swift package" and a "Swift module"? When should I use one phrase or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [Swift.org](https://swift.org/package-manager/#conceptual-overview)

> **Modules:** Swift organizes code into modules. Each module specifies a namespace and enforces access controls on which parts of that code
>   can be used outside of the module.
>
> A program may have all of its code in a single module, or it may
>   import other modules as dependencies. Aside from the handful of
>   system-provided modules, such as Darwin on macOS or Glibc on Linux,
>   most dependencies require code to be downloaded and built in order to
>   be used.
>
> When you use a separate module for code that solves a particular
>   problem, that code can be reused in other situations. For example, a
>   module that provides functionality for making network requests can be
>   shared between a photo sharing app and a weather app. Using modules
>   lets you build on top of other developers’ code rather than
>   reimplementing the same functionality yourself.
>
> **Packages:** A package consists of Swift source files and a manifest file. The manifest file, called Package.swift, defines the
>   package’s name and its contents using the PackageDescription module.
>
> A package has one or more targets. Each target specifies a product and
>   may declare one or more dependencies.

Answer (score 28):

A Swift package is a collection of source code... you can think about it as a self contained project, which has its own versions and repository. The Swift language itself doesn't know about packages currently, it is concept only used by the Swift package manager.

A Swift package can contain one or more Swift modules -- each Swift module *is* something the language knows about, and the Swift modules defines the scope of things like access control (`public`, `internal`, `private`) for example. A Swift package can also contain other kinds of targets or modules, for example it can contain a body of C source code to build into a library.

Swift packages are in some sense analogous to Xcode projects, and Swift modules are analogous to Xcode targets.

As a concrete example https://github.com/apple/example-package-fisheryates
is a *Swift package* (as signified by the `Package.swift` at the top-level), identified by its URL, and it contains a single Swift module with two sources:
  https://github.com/apple/example-package-fisheryates/tree/master/Sources.

Comment: Thank you, this analogy is very helpful

Comment: Is module a .framework or a folder comprised of .swift files ?

Comment: Purposes of both have not been described in this answer.